# Show an adaptive card in popup (using tabs configuration url) while bot is installed in msteams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I want to show a task module (not url) while bot installs (with tab) in the teams. Something like `Text` does, but a bit more interactive with drop downs and all.

[image]

I have referred to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax) to create deep link for tab and paste the link here, in app-studio manifest editor:

[image]

But this doesn't seem to work. Only an empty pop up shows following this procedure.

Can someone correct me, where I am going wrong! TIA!

Comment: Hey Swati, did you try the guides around task modules here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots using AdaptiveCards is covered there aswell. Using Task Module requires "content" for the module. Either an AdaptiveCard or a website to be shown in the window.

Comment: Hi Tim, 

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/<appId>?card={"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive","content": {"type": "AdaptiveCard","body": [{"type": "TextBlock","text": "Here is a ninja cat:"},{"type": "Image","url": "http://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png","size": "Medium"}],"version": "1.0"}}&height=450&width=450&title=<title>&completionBotId=<appId>`

I used this link in *Configuration Url*  with adaptive card

Comment: @SwatiSneha - As you can see, code cannot be formatted correctly in Stack Overflow comments. Please only post code by editing it into your question. Is Hilton's answer acceptable? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "Text" screen is not showing a Task module, it's showing a custom Configuration page for the app's Tab installation. When you create an App that includes a Tab, you have the option of creating such a "Configuration" popup that gives the user the chance to configure how your tab will actually work. See here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page

Within that configuration page, you can show whatever web content you'd like. Showing an Adaptive Card is a bit of a strange scenario considering it's a web page, but you could conceivably do this using the adaptive cards js library inside the page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards)